# UDF stop working after change cell in another WorkSheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a problem with excel UDF. I'm new to excel VBA

```
Function DOSTEPNOSC(index, stockstart, stockstop, LeadTime)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Dim result, dzisiaj As Date, x As Integer, z As Integer
        
    LT = LeadTime + 1
    dzisiaj = Month(Now())
    x = dzisiaj + LT - 13
    
    wiersz = index.Row
    
    
    If dzisiaj + LT > 12 Then
        
        
        For i = dzisiaj + stockstart.Column - 1 To stockstop.Column
            kom = Cells(wiersz, i).Value
            If kom <= 0 Then
                result = "NIE"
                Exit For
            Else
                result = "TAK"
            End If
        Next i
        
        If result <> "NIE" Then
            k = stockstart.Column + x - 1
            For j = stockstart.Column To k
                kom = Cells(wiersz, j).Value
                If kom = 0 Then
                    result = "NIE"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    result = "TAK"
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    
    
    Else
        z = dzisiaj + stockstart.Column - 1 + LT - 1
        For i = dzisiaj + stockstart.Column - 1 To z
            kom = Cells(wiersz, i).Value
            If kom <= 0 Then
                result = "NIE"
                Exit For
            Else
                result = "TAK"
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    DOSTEPNOSC = result

End Function
```

Function is working until I change value of any cell in another Worksheer (even if I leave cell empty)

Before change:
[image]

After change:
[image]

Comment: Likely you need to qualify `Cells`  (tell VBA which worksheet you want to access). If you write `Cells` without, VBA will take the active sheet.

Comment: Not sure but i think you need to make your UDF [Volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile)

Comment: Thanks for help. FunThomas was right :) I needed to specify which sheet I want to use